# Ubuntu Hadoop 2.7 HA is not enabled

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

My OS is Ubuntu 15.04 & Hadoop version is 2.7.0 by tar -xzf hadoop2.7.0.tar.gz from official website.

And some envs as following:
(I have not enought reputation. LOL )

[image]

HOSTS file:

[image]

After configuring and starting journalnode, there is a puzzled question occurring:

[image]

I was dealing with it a long time. Can somebody help me?

These are my configuration files:

core-site.xml:

[image]

hdfs-site.xml:
[image]

[image]

[image]

mapred-site.xml:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Settings in Ubuntu 15.04

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install default-jdk

$ java -version

$ sudo apt-get install ssh

$ sudo apt-get install rsync

$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P ' ' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa

$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

$ wget -c http://apache.mirrors.lucidnetworks.net/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.0/hadoop-2.7.0.tar.gz

$ sudo tar -zxvf hadoop-2.7.0.tar.gz

$ sudo mv hadoop /usr/local/hadoop

$ update-alternatives --config java

$ sudo nano ~/.bashrc

```
      #Hadoop Variables
      export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
      export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
      export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
      export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
      export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
      export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
      export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
      export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
      export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
      export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

$ source ~/.bashrc

$ cd /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop

$ sudo nano hadoop-env.sh

```
      #The java implementation to use.
      export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
```

$ sudo nano core-site.xml

```
      <configuration>
              <property>
                  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
                  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
              </property>
      </configuration>
```

$ sudo nano yarn-site.xml

```
      <configuration>
              <property>
                  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
                  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
              <property>
              <property>
                  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
                  <value> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
              </property>
      </configuration>
```

$ sudo cp mapred.site.xml.template mapred-site.xml

$ sudo nano mapred-site.xml

```
      <configuration>
              <property>
                  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
                  <value>yarn</value>
              </property>
      </configuration>
```

$ sudo nano hdfs-site.xml

```
      <configuration>
              <property>
                  <name>dfs.replication</name>
                  <value>1</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
                  <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
                  <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
              </property>
      </configuration>
```

$ cd

$ mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_data/hdfs/namenode

$ mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_data/hdfs/datanode

$ sudo chown chaal:chaal -R /usr/local/hadoop

$ hdfs namenode -format

$ start-all.sh

$ jps

http://192.168.56.10:8088/
http://192.168.56.10:50070/

I suspect you have some improper configuration on master and slave level. Please start fresh configuration from above installation document and it will work. Above link is given for Ubuntu 14.04 but it will work on other Ubuntu Versions too.

Comment: But there is a problem, the verstion of Hadoop is different. My Hadoop is 2.7.0. The link seems to be older . The configuration "fs.default.name" is changed to be "fs.defaultFS".

Comment: I have modified the answer with tested settings, it should work..Do reply back if you have difficulty.

Comment: Yes. I started Hadoop and "localhost:50070" was opened.

Comment: But I want to use 3+ VMwares to run Hadoop. As I said in Question, the hosts that "10.233.103.10 master 10.233.103.20 slave1 10.233.103.21 slave2" is configured. So I want to setup that a Namenode at master & a SecondNamenode at slave1 & three Datanodes at all VMwares.

Comment: Can you give me some infos or URLs ? It will be appreciated.

Comment: It is a sad story. When I want to setup cluster Hadoop as what Apache website says. A new problem happened that " Unable to load native library for your platform." I enter "file $HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR/* ", the result saying all libs are 64-bit... I  google it anyway.

Comment: I guess you can safely ignore native library problem. Is the environment working ?

Comment: Yeah. And I found a classmate know Hadoop coincidently. So I can ask to him. And think you for you help !